# How to deploy a Typescript React App (Create React App) on Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I can't find a good source online, everywhere they only talk about NodeJS with TS. What should I do? The best would be to have it step by step. I already have a React app written in Typescript, I just want to deploy it on Heroku, thanks <3.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try to add react build-pack for Heroku deployment?
Please follow the below steps to configure the Heroku app.

> 1). npx create-react-app $APP_NAME --template typescript
>
> 2). Install heroku cli from [heroku installation doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)
>
> 3). heroku login
>
> 4). heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack mars/create-react-app
>
> 5). git push heroku master
>
> 6). heroku open

[How to deploy and setup react build pack for Heroku doc](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-aedc28b218ae

You need to have a server and a port to serve the app. This guide provides step-by-step instructions on deploying react app with express.